# precision and scale of decimal multiplication in (My)SQL

Tags: mysql, decimal, scale, precision

Say I have two number `num1(p1,s1)` and `num2(p2, s2)` (where `p` and `s` are precision and scale, respectively).

What's the rule for computing the precision and scale of the result of `num1` times `num2`?

Intuitively, the scale would be the sum of `s1` and `s2` (because that's how you do multiplications in 1st grade!), but I can't figure out the rules for finding the precision.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you've declared the two numbers something like the following, as the syntax in your question isn't SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE decimals (num1 DECIMAL(p1,s1), num2 DECIMAL(p2,s2));
```

The precision is just the number of digits the number is stored to, and the scale is how many of these are after the decimal point.

So, you are correct that the scale as a result of a multiplication would be `s1 + s2`, but the *maximum* precision will also be the sum `p1 + p2`. The actual precision could be less than this depending on the numbers multiplied.

**Example**

Starting with numbers which could be stored as `DECIMAL(2,1)`:

```
SELECT 9.9 * 9.9;
```

gives `98.01` which could be stored as `DECIMAL(4,2)`.

```
SELECT 9.9 * 0.5;
```

gives `4.95` which could be stored as `DECIMAL(3,2)`